# React-Native Release APK Not Installed

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

[image]
My react native android app live in play store (v1.5). and I installed the app in my device and it is working fine, Now I created new release apk(v2.0) and try to install in my device, it is showing error message app not installed. The issue is that, the release apk not updating the previous version downloaded form play store.

if you have any idea about this, please help me,
Thanks

Comment: Might be a issue with you're version code. Check it

Comment: tried not working, is this something related to google play protect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`release-apk` can not update a `app from play store`. if you need to install the `release-apk` you need to uninstall the `app from play store`. And upload the `release-apk` to play store then you can update the the previous version as normal.